# One word for "the state of being unloved"

Tags: single-word-requests

See sentence below:

> I hope that if you ever feel the desolation of ____, the knowledge
>   of my admiration may be of small consolation.

Good rephrasing is also acceptable.

**Edit**  By "unloved" I mean the feeling that one is not appreciated or unwanted

Comment: Old wise man say, "Hate is not the opposite of love, apathy is."  With that in mind, does anything in the [thesaurus for apathy](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/apathy?s=t) work for you?

Comment: of being lovelorn or loveless. The desolation of lovelessness.

Comment: @Lambie I think not, unfortunately, "Lovelorn" is defined as "unhappy because of unrequited love" which assumes love on the part of the lovelorn, while "loveless" is used chiefly to describe marriage in which there is insufficient sex

Comment: What's wrong with “the desolation of being unloved”? That's by far the most natural phrasing to me. If it must be a single word, there is correspondingly [_unlovedness_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unlovedness).

Comment: *ever feel like a loser...*

Comment: @user289661 Merriam Webster: bereft of love or a lover. The great richness of the English language is that one can still write in it. A loveless marriage does not mean one where there is insufficient sex. It's one where there is no love. It could be loveless and full of sex. unlovedness may be in James but it ain't kosher.

Comment: 'Dereliction' is sometimes used for human referents. But I agree with Janus here.

Answer (score 3):

of being lovelorn or loveless (torn by love and without love).

The desolation of lovelessness.

There are several ways to say it. Some a little different from others.

Lovelessness is not receiving or getting any love from anybody.

It's like Koothrappali in The Big Bang Theory. He just cannot seem to get a girlfriend, really.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're thinking of someone who has had their love not returned, as opposed to one who has never been loved.

[Unrequited](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unrequited) means

> not requited :  not reciprocated or returned in kind, ex. *unrequited love*

For example, if Harry loves Sally, but Sally does not love Harry in return, then Harry's love is unrequited. He is in the state of being unloved.

In your example,

> I hope that if you ever feel the desolation of *unrequited love*, the knowledge of my admiration may be of small consolation.

For one who has never been loved or who has lost love, [lovelorn](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lovelorn) (Props to Lambie's comments) means:

> bereft of love or of a lover, ex., *letters from lovelorn soldiers*

Using your example,

> I hope that if you ever feel the desolation of *being lovelorn*, the knowledge of my admiration may be of small consolation.

Comment: Excellent answer for other situations, but not this one, thanks for helping me clarify.

Comment: Unrequited could fit, but only if the specific situation involved someone who loves but is unloved by the person he loves.

Answer (score 0):

How about **abandonment**?

OD:

> [**abandonment**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/abandonment): the action or fact of abandoning or being abandoned
>
> Example sentences:
>
> - ‘She had a feeling of utter **abandonment** and loneliness’
> - ‘He was rejected and outcast, and like Job, accepted his suffering and **abandonment**.’

Your example:

> I hope that if you ever feel the desolation of **abandonment**, the
>   knowledge of my admiration may be of small consolation.